# Can we use Azure Blob Storage for the ImageCache of ImageResizer

Tags: azure, imageresizer, azure-app-service-plans, imageresizer-diskcache

We basically use the [recommended cloud architecture](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v3/docs/cloud) where the source images are stored in Azure Blob Storage, the imageresizer runs on an Azure App Service  and Azure CDN is the CDN layer.

Nevertheless we are running into an issue with ImageResizer v3, [Azure App Service deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing) and DiskCache.

We use a staging slot on our Azure App Service to prevent interruptions. We also use the DiskCache plugin. Without any configuration the imagecache is written to D:\home\site\wwwroot\imagecache\ which is slot specific.

This generates two issues:

1. When we swap the slots the imagecache that is used is stale and a lot of images will be missing.
2. We always have a stale imagecache taking up diskspace on our App Service Plan, our advisor at Microsoft has recommended to use Blob Storage instead of the virtual local file system for DiskCache.

I noticed that there is no BlobCachePlugin or S3CachePlugin and I was wondering if there is a good reason for that.

My questions are:

1. Is there a reason not to store the imagecache in Azure Blob Storage using a custom BlobStorageCachePlugin that implements the ICache interface?
2. If there is a good reason, what alternative architecture do you advise to avoid the issues with deployment slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caches need to be low latency. Putting the cache on Blob Storage would make even cache hits perform terribly, likely adding 800-1800ms per request. If a Redis server were available, there are ways to make this work better, but it will still not perform as well as using low-latency storage.

Solutions to the cold cache problem:

1. Warm up the staging slot by duplicating real-world requests to it (the ideal situation, since it also warms up non-IR caches).
2. If that's not possible, then you might consider some kind of scheduled copy between the `imagecache` folders on each server that 'only adds' files. Don't try to modify or delete files or directories that are actively served.
3. Use a low-latency distributed filesystem or low-latency shared network drive. Measure the latency, though, because it's going to be a problem unless you have a very good network connection between the servers. There are blob stores that can be fast enough to use for caching, but typically only when you manage them yourself to assure low latency.

This does mean you won't be able to enable autoClean to automatically purge cache entries; set up monitoring for disk usage.

Comment: According to http://www.azurespeed.com/ the latency of BlobStorage is actually not that bad (around 40ms with sometimes a peak of 400ms). Especially since our App Service is in the same datacenter/region as the BlobStorage. Do you have hands-on experience that suggests otherwise?

Comment: I've never seen 40ms latency, maybe 100ms on a good day. if you have good latency, you could look at third party nuget packages for this. Is even 40ms extra okay for cache hits, though?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really relevant solution hosting app in Azure App Service (exactly what question author was concerned about). Having gigabytes of cached images on Azure App Service's "disk" - is really not what is recommended by Azure team. Azure webapps are not optimized for storage. It's recommended to store all static content in Azure Storage. Latency shouldn't be really that high as mentioned (if your are app is also in Azure of course), and also later on static content should be cached on client side anyway.

Comment: @LilithRiver could you please expand on your comment about not enabling autoClean? What negative affects would occur if this were enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CDN sitting in front of your Web App, then do you need the DiskCache plugin at all (or the requested Blob Storage caching)?

Once the image has been processed by the Web App it is then cached by one of the CDN edge servers, so what purpose would caching it in the Web App/Blob storage serve?

Comment: Well we have users from all over the world combined with over 300.000 possible images in multiple sizes. Our CDN cache hit rate is not high enough to solely rely on. Furthermore resizing images is very slow (in the seconds) so we rather also store the resized version in the local cache. p.s. I don't know if you're aware but if something is in cache in some edge server it is still loaded from origin from any other edge server.

Comment: We tried CDN solution as well. Unfortunately the problem with CDN is that there is big additional challenge with authorization (in case your images are restricted only to authorized users). It seems it's possible to configure some authorization on CDN, but only on Premium tier and it's rely not trivial solution..
If ImageResizer could cache images in Blob storage directly - all authorization could be done on the back-end. I.e. Blob storage is not public, and accessible only having connection string with keys/secrets/etc. Basically in same way as ImageResizer accesses "source" images.